# Adding a variable outside a function each time the function is called

Tags: javascript, addition

I am trying to add up the result of a function, after each time the function is called, here is my code:

```
function computetime(result) {
var time=0;
var mytravelroute=result.routes[0];
for (i = 0; i < mytravelroute.legs.length; i++) {
    time += mytravelroute.legs[i].duration.value;
}

var totalSec = time;
```

I want to add up the "time" variable, each time the function is called. Right now the "time" variable get over written each time, and I need to capture the value each time.

Any ideas? disclaimer: Prog lvl: peon.

Comment: Put the declaration of "time" outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var time=0;
function computetime(result) {

var mytravelroute=result.routes[0];
for (i = 0; i < mytravelroute.legs.length; i++) {
    time += mytravelroute.legs[i].duration.value;
}

var totalSec = time;
```

Comment: thanks for the help... I had to do a combination of a few answers here. I should have mentioned that "time" variable itself can't be messed with because its used to calculate hours:minutes:second later in the code....so thats where the difficulty was, final code:

Comment: ' var cumulativetime=0;
 function computetime(result) {
  var time=0;
  var mytravelroute=result.routes[0];
  for (i = 0; i < mytravelroute.legs.length; i++) {
            time += mytravelroute.legs[i].duration.value;
   cumulativetime += mytravelroute.legs[i].duration.value;
   }
  
  document.getElementById("timez").innerHTML = cumulativetime;
  
  var totalSec = time; '

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you simply need a global variable.

```
var totalSec;

function computetime(result) {
  var mytravelroute=result.routes[0];
  for (i = 0; i < mytravelroute.legs.length; i++) {
    totalSec += mytravelroute.legs[i].duration.value;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function computetime(result) {
    computetime.time = computetime.time || 0;
    var mytravelroute = result.routes[0];
    for (i = 0; i < mytravelroute.legs.length; i++) {
        computetime.time += mytravelroute.legs[i].duration.value;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this. It involves closures. You should read about scoping and closures in javascript. Here is one way to do it.

```
var tracker = {
   time: 0
   computetime: function computetime(result) {
       var mytravelroute=result.routes[0];
       for (i = 0; i < mytravelroute.legs.length; i++) {
           tracker.time += mytravelroute.legs[i].duration.value;
       }
       return tracker.time;
    }
}

tracker.computetime(result)
```